# QGIS Orfeo toolbox error when computing image statistics: "Could not find application "ComputeImageStatistics"

Tags: qgis, orfeo-toolbox

I am new to QGIS, and am trying to compute image statistics with the Orfeo toolbox (to use in a future classification project). I have downloaded the Orfeo toolbox and have it activated in my toolbar, as the image shows:

[image]

I am trying to compute the image statistics on an orthomosaic with three bands (red-green-blue). However, when I try to run the tool and save the output as a .xml file, I get the following errors:

[image]

**There seems to be an issue with the file path. How could I correct this error and run the tool?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the plugin doesn't like the space in the OTB_APPLICATION_FOLDER variable : "C:/.../QGIS 3.14/..."

when calling the application the path is cropped to "C:/.../QGIS" and applications are not found.

Can you try to install OTB in a path that does not contain spaces ?